# Registration page and post request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I want to create my own registration page with spring boot, instead of sending a JSON POST request from Postman.

I currently have an HTML page with a form which submits the registration data, a registration controller, and registration service. However, it is not working properly.

### My code:

#### RegistrationRequest

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class RegistrationRequest {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String email;
    private final String password;
}
```

#### Registration Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/registration")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationController {

    private final RegistrationService registrationService;

    @PostMapping
    public String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request) {
        return registrationService.register(request);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "confirm")
    public String confirm(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        return registrationService.confirmToken(token);
    }
```

#### HTML form

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="api/v1/registration">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Log in to tour agency account</h2>
        <p>
            <label for="firstName" class="sr-only">First name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required="" autofocus="">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="lastName" class="sr-only">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required="" autofocus="">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="" autofocus="">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
```

#### Template controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TemplateController {@PostMapping("register") // I know that "register is not linked with path = api/v1/registeration
    public String postRegister() {
        return "register";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need either need a template engine, or you could use [Javascript and submit an AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612821/spring-mvc-ajax-post) for that. If you want to use a template engine, I recommend using [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/), however there are many [template engines](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html) that are available for use.

Using Thymeleaf, you'd have to modify your template to include `th:action`, which describes your endpoint, and `th:object`, which is your model. Then we name it as `register.html`:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/api/v1/registration}" th:object="${registrationRequest}" method="post">
    <!-- Form inputs... -->
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

Then in the controller, we need to tell Spring about our HTML page and the model:

```
@GetMapping("/register")
public String registerationForm(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("registrationRequest", new RegistrationRequest());
  return "register";
}
```

So now when we open `/register`, our HTML page is loaded.

Finally, modify your POST endpoint to get our form's submitted model:

```
@PostMapping
public String register(@ModelAttribute RegistrationRequest registrationRequest) {
  return registrationService.register(request);
}
```

This returns the result from registration service, you could also return a string which represents a page name, e.g. `return "result"`, here result is an HTML page `result.html`.